# How to find file and combine `find ... -exec` and echo empty string to it?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to `echo` empty to such file types, for example:

```
bash-3.2$ cat t1.txt
aa
bash-3.2$ cat t2.txt
aa
bash-3.2$ cat t3.txt
aa
```

I've tried to make them empty by:

```
$ find /Users/liweijian/Downloads/tmpfiles -name "*.txt" -exec echo ""
> {} \;
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier in this case to avoid the quoting hassles to get the redirection to work:

Use `truncate -s 0` as command to empty the file. If it is not present, this is strange, as it should be in `coreutils` in common distributions and installed by default. Try to install this package if it is indeed missing.

Comment: I've tried `$ find /Users/liweijian/Downloads/tmpfiles -name "*.txt" -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;` , but there's an error: `find: truncate: No such file or directory`

Comment: `truncate` is in `coreutils` and should be available. Try it separately to see if it is present.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by typing:

```
 $ find /Users/liweijian/Downloads/tmpfiles -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c "echo ''
    > {}" \;
```